# Wrong value in Byte array through Perl and Java socket

Tags: java, perl, sockets

```
Perl
x=1
y=222

java
x=257
y=222
```

I understand that I can only put an integer between 0 and 256 in a byte. How to send an integer higher than 256 in a `pack(C*)` or `byte[][]`?

```
$data = $n->read($data2, 6);
@arr =  unpack("C*", $data2);
```

Sometimes when I send a value from Perl to Java, I catch a negative value in Java side, the issue is that I want to keep byte array only.

This is the java code from MousePressed on swing
(I want to send to the server the current click)

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        byte[] buff = new byte[]{02,00,(byte)p.x,(byte)p.y,00,00};
                //write buff on my socket
```

Thanks

Comment: If `x` is a byte in Java, it cannot possibly have the value 257.  Values for unsigned bytes range between 0 and 255.  And I believe all primitives in Java are signed, so Java bytes range from -128 to 127.  Please post the Java code that writes this output.

Comment: The first thing came to the mind was dataoutputstream on java side, but I think you should avoid using dataoutputstream here...

Comment: @cdhowie, we won't mention char, or boolean. ;)

Comment: @Khachik, not sure what is wrong with DataOutputStream, but you are right it wouldn't be useful if you used it, which the OP hasn't said they did. However, it wouldn't change the siutation either.

Comment: @Peter I think cdhowie meant "all numberic" :)

Comment: @Peter DataOutputStream will write integers in platform-independent way. If you use it, you should make sure that Perl reads that way. I think it is better to implement a protocol to read/write ints. Not sure though.

Comment: @Peter: Ah, good point on char.  Boolean, however, technically only considers zero and non-zero, so its signedness could easily be undefined. :P

Comment: @khachik, char ch = 5; ch++; ch += 10; etc

Comment: DataOutputStream is fine, you have to remember that java bytes are implicitly -128 to 127 so if you expect it to be another range you need it take this into account. e.g. when you print the value.

Comment: @Peter It makes char numeric? In Python: `l = [1, 2]; l + [3, 4]` makes `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, but lists are not numeric...

Comment: As cdhowie already mentioned.

Comment: char is scalar which you can perform all numeric operations on.         char ch = 55000;
        ch /= 5.5;
        System.out.println("ch="+(int) ch);
prints ch=10000.

Comment: You can convert all the int values from 0 to 65535 into a char and back again using a simple cast.

Comment: Or in my buffer I can put value for x and y on 3 bytes (each). Do you think it is a good solution?

Comment: You can use 3-bytes, but its not a natural size to use. I suggest using a 32-bit int value and not worry about trying to save one byte.

Answer (score 0):

Java bytes are signed and they will hold their sign when you try to convert back to an integer.  Therefore, if you want to extract an integer from a length-4 byte array, you need to do something like

```
int num = 0;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    num <<= 8;
    num |= byteArray[i] & 255;
}
return num;
```

If you leave out the "& 255", you probably won't get the number you were expecting

Answer (score 0):

You can send 32-bit ints in the following manner.

```
DataOutputStream dos = ...
dos.writeByte(2);
dos.writeByte(0);
dos.writeInt(p.x);
dos.writeInt(p.y);
dos.writeByte(0);
dos.writeByte(0);
dos.flush(); // assuming you use buffering.
```